# How to update Dependencies in Gradle File for an old Project?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I just cloned a project from github, but it was done using sdk 22. now we're on sdk 29, so I want to upgrade the dependencies to 28. I changed everything inside graddle file from 22 to 28.0.0 but when I sync the file it can't find the dependencies. I have sdk 28 installed. So what is the proper way of doing this. Thanks
here's the project on github. It's been recently updated
https://github.com/nkanaev/bubble

here's gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nkanaev.comics"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionName "1.6.0"
        versionCode 7
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.junrar:junrar:0.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12'
    implementation 'org.tukaani:xz:1.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: The answer below tells gradle to pull repositories from `google()`. In addition to that, please check https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html?authuser=1#sdk-manager, and updated SDK manager, install missing SDK tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Google` to repos in build scripts. And make sure, your SDK target inside SDK Manager is up to date.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}
```